# Display data layer in array format if more than 1

Tags: jquery

i am trying to set DTM datalayer for the data container. if its single name-container exists output works as expected.

```
booking:{
 unit:{
  name: "Tony"
  age: "45"
  country: "China"
 }
}
```

But, when its more than 1. not sure how to loop through elements in this format.

```
booking: {
 unit:{
  0:{
    name: "Alex"
    age: "32"
    country: "Japan"
  },
  1:{
    name: "Tony"
    age: "45"
    country: "China"
  }
 }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="data-container">
    <div class="name-container">
        <div class="name">Alex</div>
        <div class="age">32</div>
        <div class="country">Japan</div>
    </div>
    <div class="name-container">
        <div class="name">Tony</div>
        <div class="age">45</div>
        <div class="country">China</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var name = $('.name-container .name').text(),
    age = $('.name-container .age').text(),
    country = $('.name-container .country').text();

let testLayer = {
        booking: {
          unit:{
            name: name,
            age: age,
            country: country
          }
        }
    };
DTM.setDataLayer(testLayer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) object to set up `units`.

Here in the example [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) is used to iterate over the jQuery object and context selector to target the desired `<div>` element.

```js
let testLayer = {
  booking: {
    unit: []
  }
};

$('.name-container').each(function(index, element) {
  testLayer.booking.unit.push({
    name: $(element).find('.name').text(),
    age: $(element).find('age').text(),
    country: $(element).find('country').text()
  })
});

console.log(testLayer)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data-container">
  <div class="name-container">
    <div class="name">Alex</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
    <div class="country">Japan</div>
  </div>
  <div class="name-container">
    <div class="name">Tony</div>
    <div class="age">45</div>
    <div class="country">China</div>
  </div>
</div>
```